# Scope of table when using with clause

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

Below is a piece of my stored proc.

I am getting error as invalid object MyCount, Please let me know where am going wrong

```
;With MyCount AS
        ( 
            Select DispatchToRegionId ,FolderNo, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY FolderNo DESC) as Row 
            from tblTransite where FolderNo = @VAL  group by DispatchToRegionId,FolderNo
        )

    select @cnt = COUNT(*) from MyCount     
    if @cnt = 0
    begin
         set @InvalidFolderNo = @VAL 
         print 'cnt -' + cast(@cnt as varchar(max) ) + 'invalid folder - ' +  cast(@InvalidFolderNo as varchar(max) )
        return
    end

    select @Region =( Select  top 1 DispatchToRegionId  from MyCount
                    order by Row desc  )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) clearly states the following about the scope of a Common Table Expression (CTE):

```
A common table expression (CTE) can be thought of as a temporary result set that is defined within the execution scope of a single SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, or CREATE VIEW statement
```

Once you have run the first select query, you can no longer use the CTE for your next one. You may want to consider storing the data in a temporary table or table variable if you want to access it in multiple queries.

Answer (score 0):

`MyCount` is available only for the first query after it. Try to select all you need in this one query:

```
;With MyCount AS
        ( 
            Select DispatchToRegionId ,FolderNo, row_number() OVER(ORDER BY FolderNo DESC) as Row 
            from tblTransite where FolderNo = @VAL  group by DispatchToRegionId,FolderNo
        )
    SELECT 
          @cnt = (select  COUNT(*) from MyCount),
          @Region =( Select  top 1 DispatchToRegionId  from MyCount
                      order by Row desc  )

    if @cnt = 0
    begin
         set @InvalidFolderNo = @VAL 
         print 'cnt -' + cast(@cnt as varchar(max) ) + 'invalid folder - ' +  cast(@InvalidFolderNo as varchar(max) )
        return
    end
```